# Async communication between spring boot micro services

Tags: asynchronous, spring-boot, microservices, spring-rabbit

I am new to spring boot and created 2 micro services.
They need to communicate with one other in synchronous and asynchronous way.
For synchronous communication, I can use the RestTemplate.
But how to do for asynchronous calling ?
my requirement for Asynchonous is:
lets say I am querying for something from one micro service. To fetch the queried data it will take sometime because of queried for large sum of data. 
In this case, I need to save the request into some transaction table and return the response with transactionId and callBackAPI. After sometime if I call the callBackAPI with transactionId. Then I should be able to get the previously queried data.

Please help me with this.

Thanks.

Comment: checkout https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/

Comment: @Krishna You should probably update your question and define what you mean by async communication. Async can mean different things to different people, especially in the context of system design. If you mean that you need to exchange *messages* between the systems and avoid the use of a request-response paradigm (like HTTP calls), then you'll need some kind of message broker (like RabbitMQ)

Comment: @geoand I have updated the ticket. Please help

Comment: @Krishna As far as I know, there are no ready made solutions for what you need. You'll need to roll your own :)

Answer (score 3):

Two solutions :

**Async call from your client :** 
Spring provides an Asynchronous version of the RestTemplate :
[AsyncRestTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/AsyncRestTemplate.html)
with this solution, your client is asynchronous, you don't need to store the data in a table with the transaction id and stuff.

**Make your endpoint Asynchronous (if you don't need the response) :** 
Spring lets you create [asynchronous methods(services)](https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/) that you can call from your RestController. With this solution you can do what you described in the question(creating and storing a transaction id that will be returned directly to the client and start the async job).

Comment: @akil-reguig Thanks for your answer. I feel 2nd option is better approach. But I have one query here. During Async method is processing something, if the application stop/shutdown then what will happen to that Async method process ? Will it pause and resume after restart the application ? or will it stop abruptly ?
Please confirm, Thanks.

Comment: No, the application won't resume its work after a restart. If you kill the brutaly the process of your application, this will stop the thread that is running you async process and you will lose everything that is in memory. But if you just send a kill signal to you application, the application will wait until the work is done before destroying the spring context and the application.

Comment: @akil-reguig can you please elaborate "But if you just send a kill signal to you application" ? 
Also, Is there any other way to handle such situations ?

Comment: I am talking about the commad `kill`. Running on your application process id will gracefully shutdown your application (meaning if a thread is still working, it will wait until the end before shutting down). Check this article : https://dzone.com/articles/managing-spring-boot

Comment: Kindly accept my answer if it helped you solve your problem.